# Visual C++ 2008 Forms Incredibly Slow

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2008

In Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition when adding forms all of the default handlers for buttons, check boxes, etc go into FormName.h by default. So when I do this most of my handler code now goes in the header, then I switch back to the "Design View" to see the form designer. Once I have any reasonable size interface going back to "Design View" from the code view (of the header FormName.h) takes on the order of 1-3 minutes for (what I assume to be) the form designer to re-parse the header file to roundtrip any changes I may have made in the actual code.

Is there a way to change this behavior? I've done some basic Googling but haven't really found anyone complaining about this issue, so I assume I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known problem with using Windows Forms designer with C++ in Visual Studio. You have to move your definitions of member functions manually from a header file to corresponding source file. You might want to take a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/591ccd20-0404-45c3-8f18-61c965cdc1a9) thread where I raised this issue on msdn c++ group.

Welcome to Visual C++.

ps.
Developers, developers, developers, developers; Yada, yada...